# keyDown() Not working Processing

Tags: processing, keydown

I'm using Processing to make something and basically my keyDown() is not working. It supposed to be triggered when any key is pressed but the function is not being called. Code below:

```js
int playerno=0; //determines player
boolean ready=true;
void setup() {
  size(700, 700);
  background(#FFFFFF);
  fill(#000000);
  textSize(50);
  text("Press Any Key To Start", 350, 350);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (ready) {
    fill(#FFFFFF);
    rect(350, 350, 200, 100);
    fill(#000000);
    textSize(50);
    text("Game Ready", 350, 350);
    boolean ready=false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will won't work without `draw` function. Also you are declaring new local variable `ready` inside `keypressed()` this is bad mistake. Try move your drawing code from "keyDown()" into "drawing" like this:

```java
void draw() {
  if (ready == false) {
    background(#FFFFFF);     //This is needed for redrawing whole scene
    fill(#FFFFFF);
    rect(350, 350, 200, 100);
    fill(#000000);
    textSize(50);
    text("Game Ready", 350, 350);
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (ready) {
    ready=false;
  }
}
```